# How can I hide all text output in pyttsx3

Tags: python-3.x

How can I hide all output or print in **pyttsx3**

Here is some example code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

I have a `cli` project and use `pyttsx3` lib

I run the project and print the text in command line with **pyttsx**

Please see picture :  https://ibb.co/LN3jyMN

Comment: I tried to clean up a bit of the text, reduced a few things you asked twice, and added caps & sentences where they should be to help make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following

#### option 2 (updated)

```
# Add these to the top of your .py file

import os, sys

class HiddenPrints:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        self._original_stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = self._original_stdout
        sys.stderr.close()
        sys.stderr = self._original_stderr
```

then call your code like this

```
with HiddenPrints():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say("I will speak this text")
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: hello dean van greunen

Sorry, there is still a problem ...

please see ...

Method 1 : http://s8.picofile.com/file/8366889684/photo_2019_07_16_23_03_30.jpg

method 2 : http://s9.picofile.com/file/8366890068/photo_2019_07_16_23_06_07.jpg

Comment: @SYS113 i updated option 2, i never had stderr writing to nul, now it writes to null

Comment: ```self._original_stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')```

Comment: it works 100% for me, sorry reply took long, we had to reroute stdout and stderr